# Rails Omniauth google_oauth2 for admin.directory.user.readonly scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

There is my settings in omniauth.rb:

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
       {
         scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
         provider_ignores_state: true,
         prompt: 'select_account consent',
         callback_path: '/auth/google_oauth2/callback'
       }
```

Trying to open localhost:5000/omniauth/google_oauth2, select gmail account, accept **See info about users on your domain**, click **Allow** and got:

```
{"code"=>403, "message"=>"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "status"=>"PERMISSION_DENIED", "details"=>[{"@type"=>"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason"=>"ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain"=>"googleapis.com", "metadata"=>{"method"=>"google.social.boq.socialgraph.peopleapis.legacy.service.people.proto.LegacyPeople1Service.JsonGetOpenIdConnect", "service"=>"legacypeople.googleapis.com"}}]}: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "method": "google.social.boq.socialgraph.peopleapis.legacy.service.people.proto.LegacyPeople1Service.JsonGetOpenIdConnect", "service": "legacypeople.googleapis.com" } } ] } }
```

Not sure what I need to fix. Сan anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169839/1326996).

It looks like you need to add admin privileges to whichever account you're using to make the request, therefore I suggest **investigating your Google Admin Console for any possible misconfiguration** with your OAuth client credentials.